# Include single entry type with custom parameters in the for loop within multiple entry types

Tags: entry, entry-type

I have several entry types, where I want to set a special element criteria for the `entryTypeHandleX` entry type, and simultaneously loop through all entry types included `entryTypeHandleX`.

The criteria I want to set is to skip first X entries for `entryTypeHandleX`.

In my template it looks like this:

```
{# Set ECM for all sections and entry types #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section().types() %} 

{# Set ECM for all channels and special entry type #}
{% set special = craft.entries.section().type('entryTypeHandleX').offset(X) %} 

{# Set ECM for entries. Check var 'params', Where the data are coming from!!! #}
{% set entries = params.limit(10) %}

{% paginate entries as entriesOnPage %}

{% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
{# entry #}
{% endfor %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to merge two distinct elementCriteriaModels is to perform each query separately grabbing their 'ids', then merge the 'ids', and perform a new query using the 'ids' as the only parameter.

```
{% set first10 = craft.entries.type('entryTypeHandle').limit(10).ids() %}
{% set all = craft.entries.ids() %}
{% set first10-All = all|without(first10) %} 
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.limit(10).id(first10-All).ids() %}
{% set specialIds = craft.entries.type('entryTypeHandle').offset(10).ids() %}
{% set entryIDs = entryIds|merge(specialIds) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.id(entryIds) %}
{% paginate entries as entriesOnPage %}
    {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
        {# entry #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

I also notice a few other issues in your example, that might be causing you some problems.

- I see a lot of empty query parameters which are not needed — keep in mind that empty parameters will not really affect the results. (i.e. `craft.entries.section().types()` is really the same as just `craft.entries`, which, in this case, will return all entries).
- By modifying an existing query, you are essentially creating two queries to the database, which may not be what you're after.

  ```
  {% set params = craft.entries.section().types() %}
  {% set entries = params.limit(10) %}
  ```

  This works, but you are essentially querying the database twice, creating two elementCriteriaModels. A better way to do this is to use a parameters array.

  ```
  {% set params = {
     section: 'mySectionHandle'
  } %}
  ```

  If you later need to add more parameters, you can do so using the `merge` filter, before running the query. The result is that you will only be querying the database once.

  ```
  {% set params = params|merge({ limit:10 }) %}
  {% set entries = craft.entries(params) %}
  ```

Comment: Performed it and I got a PHP notice - Array to string conversion.

Comment: And thank you @Douglas McDonald for issues explanation. I'm aware of that. I actually used the code, that `craft.entries.section().types()` has variables defined. Sorry